# Send a message on a channelId from another channelId

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I would like to know if it was possible to send a message from "directline" on a conversation that is on the "emulator".

I took the id of the conversation and put it in the query. I have this error.
https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/gae5nfamid768494c/activities

`{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Unknown conversation"
  }
}`

So I wonder if it's possible or not?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: I used the default template code I posted on Azure. On the emulator I just started the conversation. I get the id of the conversation. And I have made a REST call from postman with my secret key as an authentication header. 
I did not make any special code.

Comment: And what the body of the requested contained? Please update the question with all these details otherwise it will be really hard to help you.  See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

my body is:

`{
  "type": "message",
  "text": "Salut",
  "from": {
    "id": "default-user",
    "name": "User"
  },
  "channelId": "emulator"
}`

I have sent this message from postman and I would like to see the answer on my emulator.

Comment: If I create the conversation since postman and I add the message it works but if I create the conversation from the emulator it does not work.